# Swift Realm - Iterate an array of items to update their relationships

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a basic many-to-many relation with a relation table on my Realm Schema.
So I have Recipe, Ingredient and RecipeIngredient model.

When I try to create a Recipe, I have to iterate an array of Ingredient to create RecipeIngredient. Once the recipeIngredient is create I want to edit my Recipe and my Ingredient to add a relation to the new RecipeIngredient. But the edition of the Ingredient throws an exception, and I have no idea why...

Here some code

Recipe Model

```swift
class RecipeRealm: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var name: String = ""
    @Persisted var lastEditedTime: Date = Date()
    
    @Persisted var recipeIngredients: List<RecipeIngredient>
    
    convenience init(name: String){
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Ingredient Model

```swift
class IngredientRealm: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var name: String = ""
    @Persisted var unit: Unit = Unit.none
    @Persisted var lastEditedTime: Date = Date()
    
    @Persisted var recipeIngredients: List<RecipeIngredient>
    
    convenience init(name: String){
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
    
}
```

RecipeIngredient Model

```swift
class RecipeIngredient: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var qty: Int = 0
    @Persisted var lasEditedTime: Date = Date()
    
    @Persisted(originProperty: "recipeIngredients") var recipe: LinkingObjects<RecipeRealm>
    @Persisted(originProperty: "recipeIngredients") var ingredient: LinkingObjects<IngredientRealm>
}
```

The recipe form model

```swift
struct QuantifiedIngredient {
    var ingredient: IngredientRealm
    var qty: Int16
}


class RecipeForm: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name = ""
    @Published var ingredients: [QuantifiedIngredient] = []
    var recipeID: String?
    
    var updating: Bool {
        recipeID != nil
    }
    
    init(){}
    
    init(_ recipe: Recipe){
        name = recipe.name ?? ""
        ingredients = []
        recipeID = recipe.id
    }
}
```

The create Recipe logic

```swift
private func createRecipe() {
        withAnimation {
            do {
                let realm = try Realm()
                // Create Recipe on RealmDB
                let realmRecipe = RecipeRealm(name: form.name)
                
                try realm.write{
                    realm.add(realmRecipe)
    
                    for ingredient in form.ingredients{
                        let recipeIngredient = RecipeIngredient()
                        recipeIngredient.qty = Int(ingredient.qty)
                        realm.add(recipeIngredient)
                        
                        realmRecipe.recipeIngredients.append(recipeIngredient)
                        ingredient.ingredient.recipeIngredients.append(recipeIngredient) // <--- this line crash
                    }
                }
                
            
                
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
```

An exception is throw by this line on createRecipe method: `ingredient.ingredient.recipeIngredients.append(recipeIngredient)`.

Here the error message: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Cannot modify managed RLMArray outside of a write transaction.'`
But I have the write block...

Any ideas ?

Comment: I would be helpful to know what line is throwing the error. Please step through you code line by line to determine that and update the question with the info.

Comment: Thanks. I mentioned it in my code, this line thrown the error `ingredient.ingredient.recipeIngredients.append(recipeIngredient)` in the create recipe method. I'll update my question

Comment: If I am looking at this, `for ingredient in form.ingredients` is iterating over the ingredients in the `form` which is a `class RecipeForm: ObservableObject` which is not a Realm object. So you want to add non-realm objects to Realm? Or perhaps there's more to it.

Comment: You're right about the `form`, is not a Realm object, but it contains an array of `QuantifiedIngredient` that contain an `ingredient` which is a Realm object, this is why I do `ingredient.ingredient` (the realm object) `.recipeIngredients.append()`

Comment: So this `ingredient.ingredient.recipeIngredients.` resolved to `QuantifiedIngredient.ingredient.recipieIngredients`, right? So what is `QuantifiedIngredient` and is it managed by the same realm, and/or is it a realm object?

Comment: `QuantifiedIngredient` is a struct with an `ingredient : IngredientRealm` and an int `qty`. I have only one Realm, with the default configuration. (You can see the QuantifiedIngredient struct declaration on `RecipeFormModel`)

Comment: I boiled your code down and ran it and it's working for me - no crashes and everything writes correctly. My guess is you're doing something with one of your objects on a different Realm than what it was created on - hence the crash.

Comment: Ok, this is reassuring, because I thought I misunderstand something on Realm philosophy, but no, I probably make a mistake somewhere. Anyway, thank you for your help, and I will try to update my answer when I figure out why it's crashing

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when I tried to add recipeIngredient on the ingredient, I actually tried to put a realm object on a copy of the realm ingredient. So is obviously not working, but the error message is not very clear.

To fix it I used the `thaw()`function that returns me the good realm object, so I can edit it.

```swift
try realm.write{
                    realm.add(realmRecipe)
    
                    for ingredient in form.ingredients{
                        let recipeIngredient = RecipeIngredient()
                        recipeIngredient.qty = Int(ingredient.qty)
                        realm.add(recipeIngredient)
                        
                        
                        realmRecipe.recipeIngredients.append(recipeIngredient)
                        
                        guard let rIngredient = ingredient.ingredient.thaw() else {
                                return
                            }
                        rIngredient.recipeIngredients.append(recipeIngredient)
                    }
                }
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, so if someone had a better option I'm listening :)

Comment: You should only thaw() objects that were frozen() otherwise you'll have weird behavior. **Frozen objects are not live and do not automatically update. They are effectively snapshots of the object state at the time of freezing. Thawing an object returns a live version of the frozen object.**